# Manipulation iterator list + pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, sfml

I'm trying to check all collisions of all entities. I do it like:
My parent Class "Entity" has a `static std::list<Entity*> allEntities`

The constructors of all child class have this sentence `Entity::AddEntity((*this));`

I have a property  `std::list< Entity*> m_collisionWith;` it will take all pointers of entities with intersection

After, I have a static function in the Entity class :

```
for (std::list<Entity*>::iterator it = allEntities.begin(); it != allEntities.end(); it++) //to check everything...
{

    for (std::list<Entity*>::iterator itSec = allEntities.begin(); itSec != allEntities.end(); itSec++) // ... with everything
    {

        if ((*it)->m_spriteCharacter[(*it)->m_currentFrameCharacter].getGlobalBounds().intersects((*itSec)->m_spriteCharacter[(*itSec)->m_currentFrameCharacter].getGlobalBounds()) && *itSec != (*it)) //to_check if we have an intersection between two objects
        {
            if ((*it)->m_collisionWith.empty())
            {   
                (*it)->m_collisionWith.push_back((*itSec));
            }
            else
            {
                for (std::list<Entity*>::iterator itThr = (*it)->m_collisionWith.begin(); itThr != (*it)->m_collisionWith.end(); itThr++)
                {
                    if ((*itThr) != (*itSec)) //to check if the second object is not here yet. itThr will be every objects in m_collisionWith
                    {           
                        (*it)->m_collisionWith.push_back((*itSec)); 
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I would like to check if an entity has an intersection with an another entity and if it is, I would like not add it in the m_collision.
Normally, if I have 3 entities, m_collision.size() is equals 3 but it is growing up nonstop

Comment: Don't you have to check whether the two elements you are checking for intersection is the same element?

Comment: @M.Shaw he does, its just at the end of a very long if statement

Comment: This is why I did with if ((*itThr) != (*itSec))
itThr will be all pointers in the m_collision property and itSec is the entity that the first entity touched
edit: yep  user3288829

Comment: @user3288829 Ah I missed it. @Supernirito It might be a better idea to put it at the front as short-circuiting and that it is most likely that evaluating `(*it != *itSwc)` would be much quicker than evaluating the other boolean expression.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see How do you want to do that with this code ? 
And I'm not sur you understand but it = first entity, itSec = second entity, itThr = entityWithWhatIHadAnInterection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (std::list<Entity*>::iterator itThr = (*it)->m_collisionWith.begin(); itThr != (*it)->m_collisionWith.end(); itThr++)
{
     if ((*itThr) != (*itSec)) //to check if the second object is not here yet. itThr will be every objects in m_collisionWith
     {           
          (*it)->m_collisionWith.push_back((*itSec)); 
     }

}
```

This pushes `itSec` at the back for every element in `(*it)->m_collisionWith` that is not equal to `*itSec`. It should be:

```
bool exists = false;
for (std::list<Entity*>::iterator itThr = (*it)->m_collisionWith.begin(); itThr != (*it)->m_collisionWith.end(); itThr++)
{
     if ((*itThr) != (*itSec)) //to check if the second object is not here yet. itThr will be every objects in m_collisionWith
     {           
          exists = true;
          break;
     }

}
if (!exists) 
{
    (*it)->m_collisionWith.push_back((*itSec)); 
}
```